CSS aspect-ratio not maintained when parent container's height exceeds limit
I'm working on a layout where a child element inside a parent container must always maintain a 16:9 aspect ratio. The parent container's size can be dynamically adjusted through JavaScript, and the child should adapt its dimensions accordingly.
Here's the problem:

When I increase the width of the parent container, the child adjusts correctly, maintaining the aspect ratio.
However, when I increase the height of the parent container significantly, the child's height grows beyond the aspect ratio constraints, breaking the layout.

Here’s a minimal reproducible example of my code:


var height = 90;
var width = 160;

function increaseHeight() {
  height += 100;
  document.getElementById('parent').style.height = height + 'px';
}

function increaseWidth() {
  width += 100;
  document.getElementById('parent').style.width = width + 'px';
}
#parent {
  height: 90px;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* tried to add: align-items: center; - it makes the child disappear. */
}
#child {
  height: auto; /* tried also: max-height: 100%; */
  max-width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
  background-color: yellow;
  object-fit: contain;
}

#buttons {
  position: fixed;
  left: 1em;
  top: 1em;
}
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
<div id="buttons">
  <button onclick="increaseHeight()">increase height</button>
  <button onclick="increaseWidth()">increase width</button>
</div>



How can I ensure that the child always maintains the 16:9 aspect ratio, regardless of the parent's dimensions, and without disappearing or breaking? Any help would be appreciated!

On my Mac I can observe the behaviour you describe in Chrome and Firefox, but in Safari it behaves exactly as you want it to.

To center your box inside a grid and have it respect ratio, you need absolute positioning : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ZYzQjNX centering inside a flex parent a or a grid cell shrinks the element to its content's size .

@G-Cyrillus that codepen doesn’t work on my Mac, either in Safari or Chrome. The yellow child element doesn’t maintain a 16:9 aspect ratio in tall containers.

@BrettDonald thanks for the feedback ;) the codepen was broken ...

@G-Cyrillus confirming it works now 8-)

@BrettDonald oki, great !

About the duplicate, It doesn't answer the question :) the duplicate requires to size a flex element where here, it is about a flex child without any size set that has to keep an aspect ratio and fit within the parent (centering methods shrinks it down) @temaniafif  are you sure or is it an advise to do otherwise ?

Yes. It would be nice to be able to use object-fit: contain, but that only works on replaced elements like images and videos. Elements which have intrinsic dimensions and therefore an intrinsic aspect ratio.
However, there is an alternative technique which works on any element. It uses absolute positioning.


var height = 90;
var width = 160;

function increaseHeight() {
  height += 100;
  document.getElementById('parent').style.height = height + 'px';
}

function increaseWidth() {
  width += 100;
  document.getElementById('parent').style.width = width + 'px';
}
#parent {
  height: 90px;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

#child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
}

#buttons {
  position: fixed;
  left: 1em;
  top: 1em;
}
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
<div id="buttons">
  <button onclick="increaseHeight()">increase height</button>
  <button onclick="increaseWidth()">increase width</button>
</div>



